# Python adding prefix to list elements in python

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, prefix

I have this list of strings

```
lst = ["/foo/dir/c-.*.txt","/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc","/foo/dir3/es-.*.info"]
```

and I have a prefix string :

```
/root
```

Is there any pythonic way to add the prefix string to each element in the list, so the end result will look like this:

```
lst = ["/root/foo/dir/c-.*.txt","/root/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc","/root/foo/dir3/es-.*.info"]
```

If it can be done without iterating and creating new list ...

Comment: `['/root' + path for path in lst]`?

Comment: `lst = [prefix+item for item in lst]`  - this is to reassign the result back to orig. list

Comment: You might want os.path.join() to use OS agnostic paths rather than /

Comment: This is quite simple really, you could write out a for loop- where did you efforts go wrong? You'll have to iterate, directly or implicitly of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of pythonic, but this will be also on possible way

```py
list(map(lambda x: '/root' + x, lst))
```

Here there is comparison between list comp and map [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

Also thanks to @chris-rands learnt one more way without lambda

```py
list(map('/root'.__add__, lst))
```

Comment: cute! very pythonic!

Comment: what is the diff between your solution to list comprehensions

Comment: `map()` is a built-in function that allows you to turn all the items in an iterable without using an explicit for loop. But it wouldn't be considered pythonic by many!

Comment: actually using map with lambda is normally considered less pythonic, although it's taste really for functional programmers ;)

Comment: @user63898 [check this for map vs list comp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed considered unpythonic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: Of course you don't need lambda here though, e.g. `list(map('/root'.__add__, lst))` (or better import add from operator)

Comment: Thanks @Chris_Rands I took the liberty of adding it above

Answer (score 2):

**used:**

1. List Comprehensions

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
> applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
> some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
> iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
> certain condition.

1. F=Strings

> F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals,
> using a minimal syntax. It should be noted that an f-string is really
> an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value. In Python
> source code, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with 'f', which
> contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with
> their values.

```
lst = ["/foo/dir/c-.*.txt","/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc","/foo/dir3/es-.*.info"]
prefix = '/root'
lst =[ f'{prefix}{path}' for path in lst] 

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions and string concatenation:

```
lst = ["/foo/dir/c-.*.txt","/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc","/foo/dir3/es-.*.info"]
   
print(['/root' + p for p in lst])

# ['/root/foo/dir/c-.*.txt', '/root/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc', '/root/foo/dir3/es-.*.info']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply write:

```
lst = ["/foo/dir/c-.*.txt","/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc","/foo/dir3/es-.*.info"]
prefix="/root"

res = [prefix + x for x in lst]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension -

```
lst = ["/foo/dir/c-.*.txt","/foo/dir2/d-.*.svc","/foo/dir3/es-.*.info"]
prefix = '/root'

print([prefix + string for string in lst]) # You can give it a variable if you want
```